# Arraylist Value object added to the JSON While using GSON

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, gson

Hi in my app i am using to create a JSON string. So i thought of using GSON. I have two function one is to store the arraylist and another is normal object. My problem is the ArrayList part is working fine but when i print the normal object function the arraylist object is added to the json part here is my coding

main class

```
  JsonStructure json = new JsonStructure();

             json.messages.add("msg 1");
                json.messages.add("msg 2");
                json.messages.add("msg 3");

                json.asecs.add("asec 1");
                json.asecs.add("asec 2");
                json.asecs.add("asec 3");

            Gson gson = new Gson();
             output = gson.toJson(json);
            Log.i("gson", output);


            List<JsonStructure> Allergylist = new ArrayList<JsonStructure>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                JsonStructure oAllergy_Data = new JsonStructure();

                oAllergy_Data.setIdmember("hi");
                oAllergy_Data.setIduser("hello");

                // Adding register to list
                Allergylist.add(oAllergy_Data);

            }
            Gson newgson = new Gson();
            String  newoutput = newgson.toJson(Allergylist);
            Log.i("gson new", newoutput);
```

and here is my object class

```
public class JsonStructure {
    String idpeople;
    String iduser;
    String idmember;
    ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> asecs = new ArrayList<String>();


    public JsonStructure() {

    }

    public String getIdpeople() {
        return idpeople;
    }

    public void setIdpeople(String idpeople) {
        this.idpeople = idpeople;
    }

    public String getIduser() {
        return iduser;
    }
    public void setIduser(String iduser) {
        this.iduser = iduser;
    }
    public String getIdmember() {
        return idmember;
    }
    public void setIdmember(String idmember) {
        this.idmember = idmember;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }
    public void setMessages(ArrayList<String> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getAsecs() {
        return asecs;
    }
    public void setAsecs(ArrayList<String> asecs) {
        this.asecs = asecs;
    }


}
```

my out put that look like

```
gson(21917): {"asecs":["asec 1","asec 2","asec 3"],"messages":["msg 1","msg 2","msg 3"]}
gson new(21917): [{"asecs":[],"idmember":"hi","iduser":"hello","messages":[]},{"asecs":[],"idmember":"hi","iduser":"hello","messages":[]},{"asecs":[],"idmember":"hi","iduser":"hello","messages":[]},{"asecs":[],"idmember":"hi","iduser":"hello","messages":[]},{"asecs":[],"idmember":"hi","iduser":"hello","messages":[]}]
```

my out put should look like

```
 gson new(21917): [{"idmember":"hi","iduser":"hello"},{"idmember":"hi","iduser":"hello"},{"idmember":"hi","iduser":"hello"},{"idmember":"hi","iduser":"hello"},{"idmember":"hi","iduser":"hello"}]
```

my question is

1)If the gson will display all the object that declare in the class then why the idpeople is not display only arraylist is displayed to my json

2)Should i need to create a separate object file for the Arraylist or any alter coding for my coding

Comment: everything is going good. what problem exactly do u have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whatever the JsonStructure  will contain, all that will be part of your json. if you dont want to include it in your json  remove it from class.

I personally think it is not going to harm anyone if your json will contain any extra field and that field is useful for you.

Creating an new class -

```
JsonStructure oAllergy_Data = new JsonStructure();
```

will allow your arraylist to be a part of your json. if you dont want it to include, make it separate from JsonStructure class.

Or As an alternative Json can be created like this -

```
JSONObject outer = new JSONObject();
        try {
            // field
            outer.put("EMAIL", reqModel.getEmail());
            // field
            outer.put("PASSWORD", reqModel.getPassword());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            //
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //
        }
        return outer.toString();
```

remove this line

```
ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> asecs = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Use

```
ArrayList<String> messages ;
 ArrayList<String> asecs;
```

only

Comment: this will contain extra space(bit) for transfer {"asecs":[],"idmember":"hi","iduser":"hello","messages":[]}

Comment: create an new class for this.

Comment: no other alter way ya. But idpeople is not display in the json why only arraylist is displaying

Comment: add this line    oAllergy_Data.setIdPeople("hi");

Comment: no i dont want to display the idpeople. idpeople is also one type of the object for the JsonStructure class. my question is if the gson will display all the object that declare in the class then why the idpeople is not display only arraylist is displayed to my json

Comment: i'm getting error while using ArrayList<String> messages ;
 ArrayList<String> asecs; java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.samplejson/com.example.samplejson.JsonActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: initiate it before use --> json.messages = new ArrayList<String>();   json.messages.add("msg 1");

Comment: dude this work when i initiate json.messages = new ArrayList<String>(); thanks a lot